# Undersanding definition of Riemann-Stieltjes Integral used in Edwards book

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta, stieltjes-integral

I'm trying to find an explaination of the definition of Riemann-Stieltjes Integral used on page 22 of Edwards book [RZ]:[image: extract]

This can also be accessed hopefully legally here: [Zeta](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=ruVmGFPwNhQC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false)

1) The question is where does he get 'the usual definition' of the Stieltjes Integral that I have highlighted? Any references or explaination would be good. I looked at Apostol's Mathematical Analysis, Second Edition but he makes no mention of this definition at least in a way that I can understand.

2) If I understand him correctly for example $\pi(x)$ would be $\pi(n-1)+\frac{\pi(n)-\pi(n-1)}{2}$ in the use of the prime number theory as applied to say finding the sum over primes for example $\int_a^x f(t)d\pi(t)$?

RZ, Riemann's Zeta Function (Dover Books on Mathematics) Paperback – 28 Mar 2003
by H M. Edwards (Author)

Comment: Regarding 2), what the author says is "usual in the theory of Stieltjes integrals" is not necessary. The value of $J(x)$  when $x$ is a jump-point of $J$ can be any member of the closed interval from $\lim_{y\to x^-}J(y)$ to $\lim_{y\to x^+}J(y).$  The author had to define $J(n)$ for prime-power $n$ so he chose the middle value.  Similarly for the value of $\pi(p)$ when $p$ is prime, in the integral in 2). So in the integral in 2) we do not need to re-define $\pi(x)$ if $f$ is continuous.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet "Similarly for the value of π(p) when p is prime, in the integral in 2)." when you say similarly does this mean halfway between the new and old value "So in the integral in 2) we do not need to re-define π(x) if f is continuous." why would f(x) being continious make a difference? Should that not be the $d(discontinous function)$ bit that makes the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is that changing the value of $g$ at an internal point $x_0$ doesn't change the value of $\int_a^b f(x) dg(x)$, provided that $f$ is continuous at $x_0$. The integral sum will contain either a term
$$f(\xi) (g(x_0 + \epsilon_2) - g(x_0 - \epsilon_1)) \to
f(x_0) (g(x_0 + 0) - g(x_0 - 0))$$
if $x_0$ is not a partition point or a sum of two terms
$$f(\xi_1) (g(x_0) - g(x_0 - \epsilon_1)) +
 f(\xi_2) (g(x_0 + \epsilon_2) - g(x_0)) \to \\
f(x_0) (g(x_0) - g(x_0 - 0)) + f(x_0) (g(x_0 + 0) - g(x_0)) = \\
f(x_0) (g(x_0 + 0) - g(x_0 - 0))$$
otherwise.

If $x_0 = a$ or $x_0 = b$ and $f(x_0) \neq 0$, then two different values of $g(x_0)$ will give two well-defined but different integrals.

Comment: I see the overall integral is unchanged by the definition highlighted since the two different values of $g(x_0)$ will give two well-defined but different integrals their sum will result in the desired integral it just works around the discontinuity.

Comment: I assume you're referring to splitting the integral into $\int_a^{x_0} + \int_{x_0}^b$. You would still need to show that this doesn't depend on $g(x_0)$.